# SparkSQL - can you create UDFs (User Defined Functions)?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, databricks

In the documentation, I see mention of user-defined functions:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-scalar.html

But this is showing Java and Scala examples.

I am talking about Spark SQL code like the one below. Is it possible to define and use UDFs for that?

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE bla USING PARQUET AS
  SELECT *
  FROM jaja.haha AS haha
```

I am confused why the guide is saying SQL Reference and then proceeds to show the non-SQL code.

Comment: Afaik you define and register them per coding (java, scala, ..) and invoke them via Spark SQL, but you don’t define them via Spark SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with [Databricks Runtime 9.0](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/9.0.html#sql-scalar-functions-public-preview), it's possible to define a scalar user-define function using the SQL only syntax (example from release notes):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION square(x DOUBLE) RETURNS DOUBLE RETURN x * x;
```

Consult [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html) for syntax & more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `CREATE FUNCTION`.

```
CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] [ TEMPORARY ] FUNCTION [ IF NOT EXISTS ]
    function_name AS class_name [ resource_locations ]
```

Read databricks article [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-function.html).

Comment: it's not defining the SQL function - you still need to have a code compiled